# average column size using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have huge flat files for which I need to compute some metrics. Most of the metrics are simple like row count and column count and easily accomplished. The one that is giving me issues is average column size.

For eg. here is a sample file

```
header1|header2|header3|header4|header5
this|is|1|12-Dec-1995|0xFF1
is||57|14-Jan-2014||
```

How do I calculate average column size for the file. When I do str.len() it gives me an error when it encounters non-string column.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean 'column width'? Do you want, for this purpose, to treat all values as strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by 'column size' you mean 'column width', then this should work:

```
df.fillna('').astype(str).apply(lambda x:x.str.len()).mean()
#header1     3.0
#header2     1.0
#header3     1.5
#header4    11.0
#header5     2.5
#dtype: float64
```

By the way, your file has an extra '|' at the end of the last line.

Comment: I have to add one more option in read_csv and this worked so thanks. I added dtype={'header3':np.str} for one of the columns since df could not figure out the datatype and it was failing on that.